# I can't find the source of the error C4430

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am trying to declare a pointer to Player. I can't see why I am getting:

Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed.

```
#pragma once
#include "Player.h"
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

class PlayerObserver
{
public:
    PlayerObserver();
    ~PlayerObserver();

    void attach(Player* p);
    void detach(Player* p);

    virtual void Update(Player* p);

    Player *_subject;

};
```

Comment: Make sure `Player.h` does not include `PlayerObserver.h` otherwise you will have a circular include.

Comment: Yep that was it dam I need to rethink this now.

Comment: Use a forward declaration. I mean instead of `#include "Player.h"` replace it with `class Player;` in PlayerObserver.h. There are many examples of this here.

Comment: I will give it a try thanks for the help